# Assigning single resultset to multiple variables in ssis

Tags: ssis

I have an execute sql task , where i have used an sql query to get the data, now the result of this data has to be passed to three varibales.

So in Execute SQL TASK, i have done mapping in the following way

ResultType  ------ FullResultSet
ParamterMapping --- id
ResultSet
 0        path
 1        file
 2        Type

Variables path, file and type are of string type.

when i run the package EST is throwing the following error.

**[Execute SQL Task] Error: There is an invalid number of result bindings returned for the ResultSetType: "ResultSetType_Rowset".**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to save multiple rows in your variable? If you do, don't set the result set to 'single row'. If not, your variable types have to be of type object.

Maybe have a look at this as reference, too.

http://www.networksteve.com/enterprise/topic.php?TopicId=44489

Comment: my select statement gives path,filename, file type values, based on this values, i need to load the file into my db. So if i use my varibales as object type, how can i get the values of these fields

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to implement the variable directly into an sql statement, but i don't think this is possible. You can use a 'foreach loop container' to loop through the object and execute an insert statement for every single row. You can find a reference here doing a similar job: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/64014/  (this way may lack performance because of multiple inserts)

Answer (score 0):

Having 
rsFromSql
var1,var2,var3
The quickest and simplest way is
sql task
rsFromSql <- select x,y,z from mytable
and adding a
foreachloop task with recordset ado after the executesql

### mapping the vars

if you return just 1 row from the sql task
set result to singlerow in sql task
and map the column as vars in order 
0 x
1 y
2 z
cheers